# How do I check if a particular hard disk is dynamic?

Tags: linux, partition, windows, hard-disk

What commands do I have to check the dynamic or basic type disk/volumes of the Windows partitions?

#### Topic of interest because:

- [Warning: Don't install linux on a Windows Dynamic disk!](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=116723)
- [Bug Report: When there are no primary partitions left, and Windows converts to a dynamic disk, do NOT allow partitioning!](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/909202)
- [Bug Report: Installation doesn't detect windows dynamic disk](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1077565)

---

P.S.
This Q has already been answered in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/387352/212123) of Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I think `ldmtool` is what you're looking for. On my Fedora 19 system it's in the repos.

```
$ yum search ldmtool
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
================================================================== Matched: ldmtool ==================================================================
libldm.i686 : A tool to manage Windows dynamic disks
libldm.x86_64 : A tool to manage Windows dynamic disks
```

#### Example

```
$ sudo ldmtool
ldm> scan /dev/sdc*
[
  "1bad5bbc-a4b5-42e1-8823-001014b00003"
]
ldm> show diskgroup 1bad5bbc-a4b5-42e1-8823-001014b00003
{
  "name" : "FOOBAR-Dg0",
  "guid" : "1bad5bbc-a4b5-42e1-8823-001014b00003",
  "volumes" : [
    "Volume1"
  ],
  "disks" : [
    "Disk1",
    "Disk2"
  ]
}
ldm> show volume 1bad5bbc-a4b5-42e1-8823-001014b00003 Volume1
{
  "name" : "Volume1",
  "type" : "striped",
  "size" : 3907039232,
  "chunk-size" : 128,
  "hint" : "D:",
  "partitions" : [
    "Disk1-01",
    "Disk2-01"
  ]
}
ldm> show partition 1bad5bbc-a4b5-42e1-8823-001014b00003 Disk1-01
{
  "name" : "Disk1-01",
  "start" : 1985,
  "size" : 1953519616,
  "disk" : "Disk1"
}
ldm> create all
Unable to create volume Volume1 in disk group 1bad5bbc-a4b5-42e1-8823-001014b00003: Disk Disk2 required by striped volume Volume1 is missing
[
]
ldm> scan /dev/sdd*
[
  "1bad5bbc-a4b5-42e1-8823-001014b00003"
]
ldm> create all
[
  "ldm_vol_FOOBAR-Dg0_Volume1"
]
ldm>
```

#### What if the HDD doesn't use dynamic?

Here's an example from my system.

```
$ sudo ldmtool 
ldm> scan /dev/sda2
[
]
ldm> exit
$
```

#### References

- [ldmtool: accessing Microsoft Windows dynamic disks from Linux](http://michael-prokop.at/blog/2013/02/18/ldmtool-accessing-microsoft-windows-dynamic-disks-from-linux/)

Comment: How will `ldm` behave _(exit with error code or so)_ in basic disks? ..how would we conclude whether the disk is dynamic?

Comment: Basic disks it just shows an empty list. So if the list is empty it's a basic drive, would be one way.

Comment: _(not installed the tool yet, maybe in a day or two)_ ..what's `create all`? ..also do I have to fire in all those commands?

Comment: @hash - I installed it on F19, you run it, `ldmtool` and scan run the command  `scan /dev/sda2`. I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: slm there's a tool `gdisk` as mentioned in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/a/387352/212123) (making my post cross-site duplicate?) which does the job.

Comment: should I flag the Q or is it OK to keep it here too?

Comment: @rusty - nope leaving it here is fine.

Comment: @precise - if this solved your problem can you please mark it as accepted so others know your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Tour research was very good and you actually found two answers to your question, although you may have missed them.

The linux mint forum post had a link to http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/862/dynamicdisk.jpg which shows a screenshot of microsoft's tool you will notice the word dynamic under disk0 that disk is dynamic the value you wish to see there is simple.

The other way was noted in bug number 909202 where he said that windows will chance the 'type of the partition to 0x42'. fdisk will show the partition type numbers.